# Google Analytics reporting v4 (filters)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-firebase

I am using this example https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js
I want to insert a **filter** in the body of gapi.client.request.

This is my sample code

```
function queryReports() {
  gapi.client.request({
  path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
  root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    reportRequests: [
      {
        viewId: VIEW_ID,
        dateRanges: [
          {
            startDate: '7daysAgo',
            endDate: 'yesterday'
          }
        ],
        metrics: [
          {
            expression: 'ga:pageviews'
          }
        ],
        dimensions: [
          {
            name: 'ga:date'
          }
        ]
        // filters: [
        //   {
        //     name: 'ga:pagePath=~/mypath/'
        //   }
        // ]
      }
    ]
  }
 }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
}
```

What is the format of **filters** in the reportRequest?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest), there is no field named `filters`. There is, however, a `filtersExpression` string field:

> Dimension or metric filters that restrict the data returned for your request. To use the **`filtersExpression`**, supply a dimension or metric on which to filter, followed by the filter expression. For example, the following expression selects **`ga:browser`** dimension which starts with Firefox; **`ga:browser=~^Firefox`**. For more information on dimensions and metric filters, see [Filters reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters).

So you should be able to add the following to your request body:

```
filtersExpression: 'ga:pagePath=~/mypath/'
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution is working in my project and you want give dimension_name that your choice:

```
function queryReports() {

        gapi.client.request({

            path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',

            root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',

            method: 'POST',

            body: {

                reportRequests: [
                  {

                      viewId: VIEW_ID,

                      dateRanges: [

                        {

                            startDate: '7daysAgo',

                            endDate: 'yesterday'
                        }

                      ],

                      metrics: [
                        {

                            expression: 'ga:pageviews'

                        }

                      ],

                      dimensions: [
                        {

                            name: 'ga:date'

                        }

                      ],

                      dimensionFilterClauses: [{

                          filters: [{

                              dimension_name: 'ga:browser',
                              operator: 'EXACT',
                              expressions: ["Firefox"]
                          }]
                      }]
                  }
                ]
            }
        }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"filtersExpression":"ga:pagePath=~/mypath/"
```

The above will work like charm. Please refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters).